# Which version of Joomla to use- 1.5 or 1.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7

I have to build a News based website but I am not sure whether to use joomla 1.5 or 1.7? I have been using joomla 1.5 for a while and there are many extensions available for it. On the other hand joomla 1.7 has less extensions available at present and I have heard joomla 1.5 support will be stopped by next year. So would you please kindly suggest me which version of joomla should I go for and why?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building new, build in 1.7 as 1.5 is soon to be depreciated.  While some extensions are only available in 1.5, most everything new is being written for 1.7.

1.7 has a much better ACL model and other improvements that will be useful for you.

Reasons to stay on 1.5 are limited to: 
1. I absolutely need a specific module and nothing similar is available in 1.7 (but if you are building for a client, think of the implications down the road for this decision.)
2. I am supporting many sites and reusing resources among them; all my other sites are on 1.5.  I have a migration plan to get them to 1.7 (or 2.5), but I want to do it later in an orderly manner.

If you are holding back for any other reason, you are making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you need extensions that are only available for 1.5, I'd use that. But if you can get away with using/making extensions for 1.7, I'd definitely recommend using 1.7. There will be a little bit of learning at first, but it'll make for a much easier upgrade to 1.8, and you may just find some of the new 1.7 features useful.

That's the approach we've been taking recently for our client projects. There's always a bit of a chicken-and-egg issue at first (waiting for extensions to update), but we now find there are very few things stopping us from using 1.7 as a base (although we're comfortable creating our own extensions where needed).